# Cosmos DB Search Query which takes Vertex values with any character

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, gremlin, tinkerpop

I am using Azure cosmos Db, In cosmosDB i have so many vertexes, each vertex has properties in key value form. I want to find any gremlin query which checks Vertex values which start with any character.
Filter Query is there but for azure filter query is not supported, so is there any other Gremlin query which takes Vertex properties values which start with any character?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I never tried CosmosDB myself, I have to disagree with John. According to CosmosDB's docs, *any range query on any property is processed from the index*. Hence, if you want to find all `person` vertices that have a `name` property that starts with `a`, you can do:

```
g.V().has("person", "name", between("a", "b"))`
```

A concrete example over TinkerPop's toy graph:

```
gremlin> g = TinkerFactory.createModern().traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6], standard]
gremlin> g.V().has("name", between("m", "n")).valueMap()
==>[name:[marko], age:[29]]
gremlin> g.V().has("name", between("j", "k")).valueMap()
==>[name:[josh], age:[32]]
gremlin> g.V().has("name", between("j", "n")).valueMap()
==>[name:[marko], age:[29]]
==>[name:[lop], lang:[java]]
==>[name:[josh], age:[32]]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but What is 'b'?

Comment: The letter that comes after `a`.

Comment: I am using gremlin query for search in our application ,so in search if i write 'a', so i want to give all the things related with a in vertex property values, so i want like that query ,it will give that vertex which vertex-property starts with that character.

Comment: Well, then this is your answer, no? See the examples. `marko` starts with `m`, `josh` starts with `j`.

Comment: WOW ! I was looking for something way more difficult than just 'between', really powerful ! Thanks.

Comment: @DanielKuppitz, 'b' would be a next letter in basic latin alphabet. How would I know which alphabet user is using?  Example: in German, ä is a variant of a; but in Swedish, ä is one of the last letters in the alphabet

Comment: Well, you probably know which charset you're dealing with and thus it should be easy to figure out what the next character is.

Comment: Actually, it's as easy as `(char) ((int) 'a' + 1)`.

Answer (score 2):

“start with any character” requires Full-Text search, yet Cosmos DB does not support it per their documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/gremlin-support#gremlin-steps .

JanusGraph support Full-Text search or String search, for example:

```
g.V().has('bookname', textPrefix('uni'))
```

For more info please refer to http://docs.janusgraph.org/latest/index-parameters.html#text-search

Comment: That's interesting. Spectrum Data Hub uses "sw" for Starts With:
`graph.traversal().V().has('bookname', sw('uni'))`
There's support for starts with, ends with, contains, contains any, constains all, wildcard and fuzzy. (I am a developer on the Data Hub team.)